# Having SpaceFn and normal space with Karabiner?

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I got SpaceFn to work by following this rule: "Space enables SpaceFN mode (see: https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=51069.0)". But I also want to assign normal space bar to another key (for long press to unmute in Zoom calls). I can't do that because all space key become SpaceFn. So can I have both normal space key and SpaceFn key at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

SpaceFn supports another rule: "SpaceFN: Space+b to Space (hold to repeat)", does it work?

And, there is also a [Change caps_lock to Fn on press and hold](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#caps_lock_to_fn), maybe it's better than SpaceFn.